# Array to string conversion in

Tags: php, pdo

Estou tentando fazer um INSERT em uma tabela mas está retornando o seguinte erro:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\MOClient 3.0\modulos\produtos\funEnviarPedido.php on line 25

#### Codigo

```
<?php
include "../../lib/inc_con.php";



$mesa = $_POST['mesa'];
$tamanho = $_POST['tamanho'];
$quantidade = $_POST['qtd'];
if(empty($_POST['valor'])) { $adicional = "Nenhum"; } else { $adicional = implode(',', $_POST['valor']);  }
$hiddentotal = $_POST['hiddentotal'];
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo'); 
$mysqldata = new DateTime(); 
$data = $mysqldata->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
$hora = date('H:i:s');
$produto_id1 = $_POST['produto_id1'];
if (empty($_POST['observacao'])){ $observacao = "Nenhuma"; } else { $observacao = $_POST['observacao'];  }
$produzido = '0';
$valortotal = $quantidade * $hiddentotal;
$asplo = $_POST['asplo'];
$conta = '0';



$pdo=conectar();
$buscardetprodutos=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO pedidos FROM produtos(mesa,tamanho,qtd,adicional,valortotal,data,produto_id1,produzido,observacao,asplo,conta,hora,horadeproducao) VALUES ('$mesa', '$tamanho', '$quantidade', '$adicional', '$valortotal', '$data', '$produto_id1', '$produzido', '$observacao', '$asplo')");
$buscardetprodutos->execute();


?>
```

Comment: Algum dos campos que vem do **$_POST** é um array, faça um **var_dump($_POST)** para ver qual deles.

Comment: O campo valor é um array

Comment: ["valor"]=> array(4)
["tamanho"]=> array(1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Baseado na sua resposta nos comentários.

Altere a linha:

```
$tamanho = $_POST['tamanho']
```

Para:

```
$tamanho = $_POST['tamanho'][0]
```

O campo **valor** não é o causador do problema uma vez que você não está usando ele diretamente, mas sim um implode e transformando em uma string.

Comment: Funcionou, obg..