# Imprimir Valor de um array

Tags: php, array

Boa tarde,

Quero imprimir o valor do array introduzido na função getTitleIdLocation, o que estou a fazer mal?

Obrigado desde já.

```
<?php

class Imovel {

private $title;
private $id;
private $location;


 function __construct($title, $id, $location){
     $this->title = $title;
     $this->id = $id;
     $this->location = $location;
 }

 function getTitleIdLocation(){
     return array($title, $id, $location);
     }
}



$casa = new Imovel ("Apartamento", "3", "Porto");

echo $casa -> getTitleIdLocation();


?>
```

Comment: Depende o que você vai fazer com o resultado? precisa imprimir de alguma forma em especifico?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Exibir elementos de array associativo com foreach](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/187985/exibir-elementos-de-array-associativo-com-foreach)

Comment: Outras [Exibir valor de array no php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/247424/5878) / [Array to string conversion in](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104655/5878)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Não consigo aceder à função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/400473/n%c3%a3o-consigo-aceder-%c3%a0-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o)

Comment: Essa pergunta deveria ser marcada como duplicata da pergunta que ele mesmo já fez e inclusive já foi respondido?

Comment: Eu fechei como não clara por causa deste comentário: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/400473/n%c3%a3o-consigo-aceder-%c3%a0-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o/400480#comment786145_400480 . Ora, se ali diz que tentou algo e deu errado, porque essa tentativa não está na pergunta? Do jeito que está não tem uma dúvida real, poderia até ter fechado como fora de escopo porque está só pedindo para fazer o código inteiro da impressão do *array*, o que só o autor sabe como deveria ser. Se tem um dúvida específica, deve postar essa dúvida por completo, mostrar o que tentou.

Comment: As marcadas como duplicata podem ou não responder a pergunta, porque tem um contexto que indica que é outra coisa. Na verdade eu analisei as perguntas postadas e parece que não respondem (não é certeza porque a pergunta não está clara), uma delas certamente não responder porque mostra como imprimir um *array associativo* o que não é o caso. Outras duas sequer tem um laço, não sei porque foram indicadas. A que ele perguntou antes não fala nada sobre o erro que ele está tendo agora, eu mesmo indiquei abrir outra pergunta, mas a pergunta deveria constar o problema. O prob. é outro só ñ está claro

Comment: As marcadas como duplicatas, não concordo, a minha marcação de duplicata é referente a pergunta que ele mesmo já fez a aproximadamente 2 horas, essa pergunta aqui é uma duplicata da outra do mesmo autor e mesmo texto e classes ... é só observar ...

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Mas problemas diferentes...

Comment: O problema é o mesmo @AndersonCarlosWoss observe ele quer imprimir o `array` e fez duas perguntas porque não ficou satisfeito com a resposta da primeira e com certeza não entende a filosofia do site ... ele quer fazer a mesma coisa com o `array`.

Answer (score 3):

Use o método `implode` para converter em texto.

```
<?php

class Imovel 
{

    private $title;
    private $id;
    private $location;
    function __construct($title, $id, $location)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->location = $location;
    }

    function getTitleIdLocation()
    {
        return array($this->title, $this->id, $this->location);
    }
}



$casa = new Imovel ("Apartamento", "3", "Porto");
echo implode(" ",$casa->getTitleIdLocation());
// Apartamento 3 Porto
?>
```

Fontes:

1. [Array to String PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490488/array-to-string-php)( Em inglês)
2. [Função implode](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php)

Comment: OBS: Eu estou editando. Não é uma resposta.

Comment: Meu ide de php tava travando. Eu tava tentado colar e não conseguia. Agora consegui.

Comment: Tem um erro no método `getTitleIdLocation` onde para acessar os membros privados deve se utilizar `$this` ou seja,  `$this->title` etc

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

O **echo** — Exibe uma ou mais strings

Você deve usar **print_r** — Imprime informação sobre uma variável de forma legível

```
$casa = new Imovel ("Apartamento", "3", "Porto");
echo $casa -> getTitleIdLocation();
//TROCA POR
print_r($casa -> getTitleIdLocation());
```